# shell script to find which user login first time

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux Operating System I am learning to execute some commands using Shell Script
I want to see which user login first time. what should I insert to get the user who login first time. I know who but it is not what I want. Please help

Comment: do you mean the user which logged first and is still logged in?

Comment: ya it is like that only

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand your question. You want to do something based on the first ever logon of a user? or based on the first logon to a system? who is good for who's currently connected, last shows last logins of users (linux)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the user who is logged first from the currently logged in users, you can do something like this:

```
 who | awk '{print $3 " " $4 " "$1}' | sort | head -1
```

Basically, take the output of `who`, sort by the login time  and get the first row.